# Java: difference of chars

Tags: java, eclipse, data-structures, integer, char

I'm experimenting with characters in Java

**snippet 1**

```
char c='b'-'a';
```

**snippet 2**

```
char c='b'-'c'; // error: java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to char
```

Why doesn't the operation work as opposed to snippet 1, but works when I cast it to char

Comment: [I cannot reproduce the behaviour for the 1st example (`ideone.com`)](https://ideone.com/BzVC4x).

Comment: I'm using Eclipse IDE

Comment: As for the 2nd snippet: although `char` values are essentially numbers, they must not be negative. Thus, if we subtract `'c'` from `'b'`, the result is negative and cannot be transformed in a `char`. Hence: compilation error.

Comment: In Java a `char` is a 16-bit unsigned integral type. Snippet 1 does not output `A` here.  In fact using `jshell` I get `jshell> int a = 'b'-'a', b = 'b'-'c';
a ==> 1
b ==> -1` which is why you get an error on Snippet 2. You can't put `-1` in an unsigned 16-bit integral type.

Comment: Understood thanks both :)  I'm now getting 'A' as an output for 'c'-'b' as well which is still weird.

Comment: By the way, the **`char` type is essentially broken** since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters. Instead , use [code point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integers to represent individual characters.

Comment: The arithmetic operator convert 'b' and 'c' to int.   The right side is int but left side is char.  You will need to cast the ride to char again.  ```char c = (char)( 'a'-'c');```

Comment: Interesting! Can you elaborate more on why/how to use code point integers @BasilBourque

Comment: @Atharva How: `"a".codePointAt( 0 )` is 97. Why: `"".length()` is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java char is an unsigned(non-negative) 16-bit integral type.

Therefore snippet 2 is prone not to work which essentially is performing: 98-99 ('c'-'b')

And for snippet 1 it is indeed expected to show some unprintable character but Eclipse is weirdly printing A as an output

[image: Output]

Comment: This doesn't print A on my macOS - probably the font being used by the console.

Comment: Regardless of the font,  the difference of adjacent descending ASCII characters should be the constant `1` or some default.   In actuality it is a CTRL-A.